# Remove key-value pairs from string when only key is given

Tags: c++, c, strings, parsing

I have a need to parse strings that contain pairs of `key : value`, and remove a specific pair, when I'm only given the key.

Example:

Given the string `char *in = "sha-auth privacy-protocol des authentication-password shapass123 privacy-password despass123 admin-status enabled";`

and the key-word `char *kw = "authentication-password";`

I want to get only `char *output = "sha-auth privacy-protocol des privacy-password despass123 admin-status enabled";`

where the pair `{"authentication-password" : "shapass123"}` was removed.

This is my take:

```
void remove_key_word_value_from_string(char *input, char *output, char *kw)
{
    char *p = input;
    char *kw_loc = strstr(p, kw); /* check if kw is in input */
    if(kw_loc)
    {
        size_t offset   = (size_t)(kw_loc - p);

        strncpy(output, p, offset); /* copy until kw */
        p = kw_loc + strlen(kw);    /* move p past the key-word location */
        while(isspace(*p++));       /* skip all white-spaces after keyword */
        while(!isspace(*p++));      /* skip the value associated with keyword */
        strcpy(output + offset, p); /* copy rest of input */
    }
    else                            /* no censoring is needed*/
    {
        strcpy(output, input);
    }
}

char o[1024] = "";
char *in = "sha-auth privacy-protocol des authentication-password shapass123 privacy-password despass123 admin-status enabled";
remove_key_word_value_from_string(in, o, "authentication-password");
printf("output = %s\ninput  = %s", o, in);
```

I wrote in C, but open to additions / changes in C++ as my code will actually run on a C++ compiler.

Comment: "This is my take" Does it work? For what inputs did you test it?

Comment: `{ "sha-auth" : "privacy-protocol" } { "des" : "authentication-password" }` ... your input isn't actually key-value pairs separated by spaces. Searching won't work in any case, since `"... authentication-password privacy-password privacy-password despass123 ..."` will give you the wrong result.

Comment: @Mast well yeah, I tested it and it works as expected.

Comment: @user673679 I don't understand. My string contains pairs separated by white-spaces. Why do you think it is not *actually key-value pairs separated by spaces*? and why *searching won't work*?

Comment: @CIsForCookies 1. The input string above starts with `"sha-auth privacy-protocol"`. is "sha-auth" a key value? 2. What if a given password is the same as a key value and occurs before that key value? Searching for the key value will find and remove the password and the next key value, whatever that is.

Comment: @user673679 1) What I meant is that the string can have words not as a part of key:value, but it also would contain at least one such pair.  2) Indeed. But this is considered as a bad password in the guidelines provided for the device, so I don't expect any such mishap.

Comment: @CIsForCookies: 'so I don't expect any such mishap'... if I were you I wouldn't expect anything, especially users following the provided guideline. At least check the password when the user chooses it.

Comment: @CIsForCookies 1. The possible inputs need to be better defined for us to help. Is your input any string that may or may not contain key-value pairs (this is the current definition)? Is your input always that exact string? Is your input that exact string but with different passwords? Is the first word always "sha-auth"? What are valid values for passwords (e.g. strings in quotes with spaces? or are quotes password characters?)? 2. Uh, perhaps we should ensure that it works anyway, rather than hoping?

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things we don't see in your code, such as the way the memory for the `output` is allocated. The easiest way is to `malloc` as many bytes as needed for the the `input`, but it isn't optimal. It isn't optimal to allocate buffers every time you extract a key/value pair from the string anyway.

In C++, you would probably use iterators and make the transformation in place -keeping a copy of the original string if needed. Iterators are great, because they aren't tied to a particular container; they're an abstraction to describe a range.

Here's what I'd do:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <cctype>

template <typename Iterator>
auto skip_word(Iterator first, Iterator last) {
    auto is_space = [](unsigned char c) { return std::isspace(c); };
    // why a lambda? 1) to convert the argument to unsigned
    // and 2) to allow deduction in template context
    return std::find_if(
        std::find_if(first, last, std::not_fn(is_space)),
        last, is_space);
}

template <typename Iterator>
Iterator remove_kv(Iterator first, Iterator last, Iterator kv_first, Iterator kv_last) {
    auto kv_loc = std::search(first, last, kv_first, kv_last);
    if (kv_loc == last) return last;
    auto kv_end = skip_word(std::next(kv_loc, std::distance(kv_first, kv_last)), last);
    return std::rotate(kv_loc, kv_end, last);
}
```

`std::find_if`, `std::search`, `std::rotate` are standard algorithms, very much optimized, with parallelized versions in the oven. `std::rotate` is useful in a wide range of situations: it performs a left rotation where its second argument becomes the first element of the range, and returns the new position of its first argument. So `remove_kv` returns the iterator past the expurgated sentence, which becomes available without memory allocation. The return value is also the beginning of the key/value pair, which can be reused.

Comment: output is allocated in `char o[1024] = "";` and then sent to function

Comment: As pointed out above, searching doesn't work in the case where a password is the same as a key value. I think one actually has to parse the key value pairs (but the input isn't key value pairs, so...)

Comment: @CIsForCookies: right. But it only confirms what I thought, this is suboptimal

Comment: @user673679: yes, clever, I hadn't thought of it. My purpose was to illustrate the C++ way but maybe I should have taken it into account. That said it becomes a whole new approach if your parse the key-value pairs first

Comment: @papagaga sub-optimal because of extra bytes I allocate? If this is the case it should not concern

Comment: @CIsForCookies: that's what I meant indeed. I believe one should try to minimize memory allocation if possible. Besides, if the input string grows beyond 1024 characters for some reason, you'll also have a problem.

Comment: @papagaga Indeed. But that overflow is taken into account, and 1024 bytes is not a problem, especially when it is freed after this tiny function returns

Comment: There is also `std::find_if_not` if you find it too onerous to include the negation in the lambda, no need to use `std::not_fn`.